# I'd like to know better ways to repeat a function every certain period of time

Tags: python, scheduler

I want to repeat a function every 5 minutes, but not like 12:03, 12:08, 12:13, but like 12:05, 12:10, 12:15. I tried apscheduler, which is really great and easy to use, but I don't think it goes well with certain graphic libraries because my program stops whenever I plot data and use the apscheduler at the same time.

Therefore, I have made simple code which executes a function every 5 minutes in the way I want it to.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time


def repeatingFunc():
    print("It's been 5 minutes!")


while True:
    untilFour = datetime.now().minute % 5 
    time.sleep(20)

    if untilFour == 4:
        while True:
            untilFive = datetime.now().minute % 5 
            time.sleep(0.5)

            if untilFive == 0:
                repeatingFunc()
                break
```

Now I wonder if there are better ways to do this more effectively, using less resources. I'd appreciate it if I could get some advice on the matter.

Comment: You should use the native methods of the graphic libraries to schedule a callback. `time.sleep` pauses the whole thread, and therefore is generally not appropriate to call in a GUI thread. For instance, if you're working with `tkinter`, you should use the `after` method .

Comment: Or you can use [**`signal`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html)